# Magento 2: How to redirect to different urls using if else conditon in Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

This is my observer code:

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
        
        $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            
            
            //I am using this code please have a look at this
            foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) { 
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
            
            if($is_priscription != "" && $is_priscription == '5431'){
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            }
                else{
                    $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
                    //$redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                    $redirect->setPath('order-success');
                    return $redirect;
                }
            }
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use responseFactory as well in your else part?

```
$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

Not related but do not use object manager inject them in class constructor

```
$objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')
```